A gitignore file doesn't seem to allow dot slashes for file paths
I have a git repository called Timeline and this is where my .gitignore file is located (at the root of Timeline). In Timeline I have my node_modules directory at: Timeline/timeline-react/node_modules. How come I can't use in .gitignore the following?:
./timeline-react/node_modules

This does NOT ignore the files in the node_modules directory.
However it does work when I do this (without the dot at the beginning):
/timeline-react/node_modules

Thanks in advance for any help.

this is how they implemented it, it is documented in git help gitignore (in the PATTERN FORMAT section). Ignore patterns are either "at any level below the dir of current .gitignore", or "starting from the dir of current .gitignore". It doesn't make sense to expect patterns to match absolute paths on disk, or to start with ../, so I guess there was no need to implement ./.
